# How to apply mongodb query on List<T> in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am developing simple web services in c# using MongoDB. I get stuck in one place, In my mongoDocument I have list of userIds as below(just for example),

```
"_id" : ObjectId("57ce7aa1c54ec61774f0a91d"),
"MobileNumber" : "9652365485",
"Password" : "aaaaaa",
"Countrycode" : "+91",
"Email" : "test@xyz.com",
"CurrentDate" : ISODate("2016-09-06T08:13:22.859Z"),
"ModifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-09-06T08:13:23.211Z"),
"Location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
                23.464464,
                -73.326464
        ]
},
"FriendList" : [
        "57ce7aa1c54ec61774f0a91d",
        "57ce7aa1c54ec61774f0a91d"
],
```

Now I am fetching this all UserIds from friend list and make a list of Users like this,

```
     List<Users> friendList = new List<Users>(); 
     friendList = FriendListById(UserId); //This method will return all my friends which is in "FriendList" array in document.

public List<Users> FriendListById(string userId)
        {
            MongoCollection userCollection = db.MongoDatabase.GetCollection("UserMaster");
            List<Users> userList = new List<Users>();
            string[] friendIdList;


                    var loginUser = userCollection.FindAs<Users>(Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse(userId)));
                    if (loginUser != null)
                    {
                        friendIdList = loginUser.FirstOrDefault().FriendList;

                        for (int i = 0; i < friendIdList.Length; i++)
                        {
                            Users user = userCollection.FindOneAs<Users>(Query.EQ("_id", ObjectId.Parse(friendIdList[i])));
                            userList.Add(user);
                        }

                        return userList;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return userList;
                    }
                }
        }
```

Above method returns full details of users which are in my FriendList(In this friend list I just store Id as per above given collection example.) and I pass login user Id in this method so it will return me friend list of that user.

Noe I have full details Of all friends in this list(This all friends(users) are also in same collection).

Now, I want find particular users(like search using nearby friends, using particular name query etc.) from this FriendList using mongo query. please give me solution for this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I still don't think that I understand the question here. You retrieved an User, got user ids of his friends. Retrieved each friend and added in an array and  returned back.

I didn't understand this segment -> "Now, I want find particular users(like search using nearby friends, using particular name query etc.) "

Do you want to search users with Name instead of Id? It's a tad unclear.

Comment: @Prateek, I have frinedList in form of generic List<Users> right. this list have N number of users, I want to find several users using mongoQuery from this list. In short I want to apply mongo Query on this list. got my point?

Comment: You have a List<Users> already. Right at this point you can just use LINQ to query on it. Why specifically you'd need MongoQuery on it?

Comment: Because I want get nearby friends from my friend, so for find that, mongoDB have Qurey.near() method, so using this method I want to get nearby friend list by using Location.

Comment: Okay, understood, I dont think you can run Mongo Queries directly on a List but as you're using an old mongo driver, I'd have a look and let you know.

Comment: okay sure, let me know when you get anything, thank you @SwagataPrateek

Answer (score 0):

If you have already fetched the item a single Linq would be fine:

```
List<Users> friendList = new List<Users>(); 
friendList = friendList.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id=="yourId");
```

If you want to go for a mongodb query to search whether someone is somebody's friend, you have to look for a user id in some user's FriendList:

```
var filter = Builders<Users>.Filter.ElemMatch(x => x.FriendList, x => x == "your_id");
var res = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Then you go around the list `res` and search for those users in your User Collection.

But if you want something like `populate()` in Mongoose, I don't think there actually is any official implementation yet in .net driver.

Comment: Thanks @Prateek for quick response. I think you cannot get properly, I edit this question for more understanding. please check It once and give me solution for it.